# Angular template: Use variable value as DOM element type

Tags: angular, angular-template

I have a component and would like to render it as `div` or `span` dynamically. So I defined an input variable elementType. Now I would like to render it in a template.

Pseudo code:

```
<{{elementType}}>Content of the element</{{elementType}}>
```

This does of course not work, it`s a template rendering error. I could of course do something like

```
<div *ngIf="elementType == 'div'">Content of the element</div>
<span *ngIf="elementType == 'span'">Content of the element</span>
```

But I have to repeat myself with this, and in a more complex real world example, this is a mess.

What is a good way of handling this requirement?

Comment: I think you are going at it the wrong way. Why would you want to use different element tags? Perhaps there is another way to what issue you want to overcome with your "different elements"

Comment: This sounds like something you should solve using css, for example by setting a class on a root element and saying that all direct children should be `display: inline` if you want them to behave as spans

Comment: I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-div-span-uon232?file=src/app/app.component.ts) showing a possible approach. Keep in mind that you do need an anchor (a dom element) to insert elements, so a "container" is nescessary

Comment: @MikeS. - Thank you this works. But it is kind of un-angularic to directly manipulate the DOM, you are working against the framework. I\`m not even sure, it variables inside the container would be interpreted.

Comment: @ShamPooSham, @Poul Kruijt - Yes, you normally don\`t need this, and can work with ng-template or css. But in some cases, it would be great to have it. I have such a case.

Comment: @user1383029 This was an example to show you the possible approach, you of course probably want to create a component to show your info and display that instead - however this takes a little bit more time to implement ;) This is also why I only posted this as a comment, opposed to as an answer

Comment: Could you elaborate on why those solutions aren't good enough for your situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, my solution with ngTemplate:

```
<ng-template #inner>
    The complex inner part
</ng-template>

<div *ngIf="elementType == 'div'">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="inner"></ng-container>
</div>
<span *ngIf="elementType == 'span'">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="inner"></ng-container>
</span>
```

That`s ok, and I do not repeat myself, even if the inner part is complex. Disadvantage: If I would like the element to be `p`, `h1` or whatever else, I always have to add a new line to the template.

Better ideas which are able to fullfill the requirement without this limitation?

Comment: You either have to add an extra block of logic in a complicated directive or add a simple block of html in your component. I'd say this is probably the right approach